# Android верстка отображется только верхний TextView

Tags: android, textview

В layout присутствуют несколько вертикально расположенных TextView но отображается только один,верхний.

Что не так, как исправить?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#dcd8c8"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/txt91"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="Глава №1"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt92"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/text103"/>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Зачем вы второй TextView поместили в ScrollView?

Comment: чтоб текст прокручивался ,а что не так ?

Comment: я так понял что моя проблема в том что мне нужно указать wrap_content в первом textview

Comment: да, вы указали первому `TextView` занимать всю площадь контейнера (`LinearLayout`), в который он вложен (высота и ширина `match_parent`) - он и занимает ее, остальным не осталось места,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

изменить на

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

или какое-то значение в `dp`. Первый элемент у Вас растягивается на весь экран и остальные, соответственно, уже сжаты в 0.